# Flatten multidimensional array 1 level php

Tags: php, hierarchy

I am building a hierarchy for categories.

I am using a recursive function to build child parent relationship. This builds a nested set of arrays for each child.

I want to flatten this nested array to 1 level. There are lots of ways to completely flatten a multidimensional array, but I want to rebuild the array for JSON, maintaining each **category id** and **name** together in the array.

I get this output:

```
array(2) { 
    [0] => array(2) {
        ["id"] => int(223)    
        ["name"] => string(12) "child of top" 
        ["parent"] => int(222)
    }  
    [1] => array(1) {    
        [0]=> array(2) {      
            [id] => int(224)      
            ["name"] => string(21) "child of child of top"    
            ["parent"] => int(222)
        }
    }
}
```

But I would like to have:

```
array(2) { 
    [0] => array(2) {
        ["id"] => int(223)    
        ["name"] => string(12) "child of top" 
        ["parent"] => int(222)
    }  
    [1] => array(2) {      
        ["id"] => int(224)      
        ["name"] => string(21) "child of child of top"
        ["parent"] => int(223)
    }
}
```

Which I can then build into the correct child parent relation.

It is the first time I am building this kind of structure so I am a little overwhelmed with trying to format things correctly.

Any recommendations to move forward with this?  Thanks.

**edit** added function

```
  function display_children($cat_id, $level) { 

            $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die ("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, content, parent_id 
                                        FROM table
                                            WHERE parent_id = ?
                                        ");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $cat_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $stmt->close();

            while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                $data_array[] = $row; 

                $data_array[] = display_children($row['id'], $level+1);
            }
            return $data_array;
        }
```

**more info**
The first suggested answer isn't quite there as the children from all levels are not being returned up the parent levels.

```
parent: int(229)\n
       recursion[0]: array(3) {\n  [\"id\"]=>\n  int(232)\n  [\"content\"]=>\n  string(7) \"level 4\"\n  [\"parent_id\"]=>\n  int(231)\n}\n
            array(2) {\n    [0]=>\n  array(3) {\n    [\"id\"]=>\n    int(231)\n    [\"content\"]=>\n    string(7) \"level 3\"\n    [\"parent_id\"]=>\n    int(229)\n  }\n  
                            [1]=>\n  array(3) {\n    [\"id\"]=>\n    int(232)\n    [\"content\"]=>\n    string(7) \"level 4\"\n    [\"parent_id\"]=>\n    int(231)\n  }\n}\n 
parent: int(228)\n
        recursion[0]: array(3) {\n  [\"id\"]=>\n  int(231)\n  [\"content\"]=>\n  string(7) \"level 3\"\n  [\"parent_id\"]=>\n  int(229)\n}\n
            array(2) {\n    [0]=>\n  array(3) {\n    [\"id\"]=>\n    int(229)\n    [\"content\"]=>\n    string(7) \"level 2\"\n    [\"parent_id\"]=>\n    int(228)\n  }\n  
                            [1]=>\n  array(3) {\n    [\"id\"]=>\n    int(231)\n    [\"content\"]=>\n    string(7) \"level 3\"\n    [\"parent_id\"]=>\n    int(229)\n  }\n}\n 
parent: int(227)\n
        recursion[0]: array(3) {\n  [\"id\"]=>\n  int(229)\n  [\"content\"]=>\n  string(7) \"level 2\"\n  [\"parent_id\"]=>\n  int(228)\n}\n
            array(2) {\n    [0]=>\n  array(3) {\n    [\"id\"]=>\n    int(228)\n    [\"content\"]=>\n    string(7) \"level 1\"\n    [\"parent_id\"]=>\n    int(227)\n  }\n  
                           [1]=>\n  array(3) {\n    [\"id\"]=>\n    int(229)\n    [\"content\"]=>\n    string(7) \"level 2\"\n    [\"parent_id\"]=>\n    int(228)\n  }\n}\n
```

Final output for JSON:

```
   [{\"id\":228,\"content\":\"level 1\",\"parent_id\":227},{\"id\":229,\"content\":\"level 2\",\"parent_id\":228}]"
```

using this check in the loop:

```
  if( isset( $recursion[0] ) ){
      $data_array[] = $recursion[0];
         echo " parent: ";
         var_dump($cat_id)
         echo "recursion[0]: " 
         var_dump( $recursion[0], $data_array);
 }
```

I think I have the answer:

```
if( isset( $recursion[1] ) ){
  $data_array = array_merge($recursion,$data_array);
} elseif ( isset( $recursion[0] ) ){
  $data_array[] = $recursion[0];
}
```

If there is more than 1 value in the recursion return then there are children of children being returned up the recursion.  More than just the child of the current parent. It is required to return the whole recursion array. Then merge the array with the current parent. I haven't tested this thouroughly yet, but seems to be going well.

Comment: what function did you use to add the nested array to the parent? Maybe you just need to replace an array_push($parent,$child) with $parent[]=$child

Comment: Hi. I have added the function fyi. I was trying to figure a way to avoid the nested array, but couldnt quite get there.

Comment: seems like you need a condition to check if you're working with the array with children or with "empty" array holding the correct array item

Comment: Interesting, that might be what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the structure is as the example this should work:

```
function display_children($cat_id, $level) { 

        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die ("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, content, parent_id 
                                    FROM table
                                        WHERE parent_id = ?
                                    ");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $cat_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();

        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $data_array[] = $row; 
            $recursion = display_children($row['id'], $level+1);
            if(isset($recursion['id']))
               $data_array[] = $recursion;
            elseif(isset($recursion[0]))
               $data_array[] = $recursion[0];
            else
               //manage error
        }
        return $data_array;
    }
```

Comment: Nice, it makes sense but is difficult to quite lock my mind into the whole recursive process. Calling itself and returning the value to itself, and this last little bit needed to isolate the process. Thankyou!

Comment: turns out I am not quite there yet. when there is more children of children they seem to be ignored. I have added a more complete output from the recursive call var_dump($recusive);

Comment: I don't really understand your added informations, can you post the source case, the expected result and the actual (wrong) result ?

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to work this out, I understand that the first recursion check isn't needed, and the issue is that the return cannot pass the recursion checks back up through the recursion levels.  I have changed the further info to display the parent being queried and the returns for the recursion.